# Title em URL amigável

Tags: php, url

Como que eu faço pra trocar o `title` das páginas fixas na URL amigável?

abaixo segue o script da url amigavel

```
<div id="conteudo">
   <?php
    $url = $_GET['url'];
    $quebraUrl = explode('/', $url);                
    $categoria = $quebraUrl[0];                 
    $paginas = array('home', 'empresa', 'servicos', 'produtos', 'noticias', 'dicas', 'fale-conosco');


    //HOME
    if(!isset($categoria) || $categoria == ''){
        include("paginas/home.php");
    }
    //PAGINAS FIXAS
    else if(isset($categoria) && in_array($categoria, $paginas)){
        include("paginas/".$categoria.".php");  
    }

  ?>                   
</div>
```

e abaixo o menu.php

```
<div id="menu">
        <ul id="categoria">
            <a href="<?php echo URLBASE; ?>/home" title="#"><li>HOME</li></a>
            <a href="<?php echo URLBASE; ?>/cursos" title="#"><li>CURSOS</li></a>
            <a href="<?php echo URLBASE; ?>/video-aulas" title="#"><li>VÍDEO AULAS</li></a>
            <a href="<?php echo URLBASE; ?>/artigos" title="#"><li>ARTIGOS</li></a>
            <a href="<?php echo URLBASE; ?>/tutoriais" title="#"><li>TUTORIAIS</li></a>
            <a href="<?php echo URLBASE; ?>/dicas" title="#"><li>DICAS</li></a>
            <a href="<?php echo URLBASE; ?>/noticias" title="#"><li>NOTÍCIAS</li></a>
            <a href="<?php echo URLBASE; ?>/fale-conosco" title="#"><li>FALE CONOSCO</li></a>
        </ul>


    </div>
```

e abaixo o header.php

```
<?php require_once("sistema/config.php"); require_once("sistema/funcoes.php"); error_reporting(0); ?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Project WEB - Códigos, Scripts, Dicas de Programação e muito mais!</title>
<link href="<?php echo URLBASE; ?>/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<!-- CORPO -->
<div id="corpo">

    <!-- HEADER -->
    <div id="header">
        <!-- LOGO -->
        <div id="logo">
            <a href="<?php echo URLBASE; ?>/home" title=""><img src="<?php echo URLBASE; ?>/imagens/logo.png" alt="imagens/logo.png" title="Project WEB - Códigos, Scripts, Dicas de Programação e muito mais!"></a>
        </div>

        <!-- MENU -->
        <?php include_once("includes/menu.php"); ?> 
    </div>
```

Comment: Olá sergio, existe um menu horizontal e estou usando url amigavel, porem o titulo das paginas não troca, gostaria que trocasse

Comment: O title é defenido dentro da tag `title` no `head`. Sabe como fazer isso?

Comment: sinceramente não sergio poderia me ajudar por favor

Comment: Ok, melhor. Mais uma duvida: Está a abrir páginas e ficheiros diferentes, certo? Quando usa isto: `<a href="<?php echo URLBASE; ?>/home" title="#"><li>HOME</li></a>` então não passa nenhum parametro GET ou POST... é só este o código que têm? tem um ficheiro de PHP para cada página?

Comment: é só isso mesmo amigo que tenho

a header.php
menu.php
e conteudo.php

e as paginas que não possue nada somente um h1 pra mostrar

Comment: Oi charlie, eu gostaria que ao clicar na determinada pagina alterasse o titulo, da forma como esta o titulo não muda, a pagina muda e o titulo permanece o mesmo poderia me ajudar

Comment: Voce precisa definir uma variavel para usa-la dentro da tag title.

Comment: não sei como, poderia me ajudar charlie não sou muito bom em php estou aprendendo

Comment: Ok, porque nao usa o modelo de url amigavel que passei ao inves disso que voce usa? Crie uma var `$teste ="meu titulo"; ` e no titulo use `<title><php? echo $teste; ?></title> `

Comment: qual modelo charlie ?
não estou vendo

Comment: Acredito que o conjunto de classes aqui http://github.com/szagot/config irá te ajudar a afazer separação, em especial a classe Uri (http://github.com/szagot/config#uri).

Answer (score 1):

Bem pelo que percebi, isso é apenas uma questão de lógica.

No seu arquivo, **config.php** acredito eu que seja nele que você esteja resgatando a url, você poderia criar uma variável para conter o titulo.

```
<?php
$titulo = 'Titulo Padrao';

if($url == 'home')
   $titulo = 'Inicio';
else if($url == 'cursos')
   $titulo = 'Cursos';
?>
```

No arquivo **header.php** onde se localiza a tag  você iria imprimir o valor da variável.

```
<title><?php echo $titulo; ?></title>
```

É uma sugestão rápida para seu problema, porém aconselho você a trabalhar de forma mais inteligente, separando a View "HTML" dos códigos php.

Procure se informar sobre Classes como o [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net) que podem facilitar sua vida em questão de estruturação de códigos e tals.

Comment: O [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) parece bem mais moderno.

Comment: Vou dar uma estudada nele brasofilo ;)